# How to switch motor outputs and use E1 as X, in Marlin firmware?

Tags: marlin, reprap

I broke up my electronics and now the output for X is not working. The stepper is OK.

There is any simple solution to remap the output pins? I want the E1 output to act as the X output.

Comment: If the answer below fixed your problem could you please accept it, using the "Tick icon" next to it, in order to remove it from the [unanswered questions](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered) list?

Answer (score 6):

When using [Marlin firmware](http://marlinfw.org/) you could easily change the pin layout of the extra extruder (E1) with the broken X stepper pins by changing the [pins_RAMPS.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/pins_RAMPS.h) file.

[Download](http://marlinfw.org/meta/download/) the firmware and open the firmware project in [Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software). Navigate to the "Steppers" section of the [pins_RAMPS.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/pins_RAMPS.h) file and replace:

```
#define X_STEP_PIN         54
#define X_DIR_PIN          55
#define X_ENABLE_PIN       38
#define X_CS_PIN           53
```

for:

```
#define X_STEP_PIN         36
#define X_DIR_PIN          34
#define X_ENABLE_PIN       30
#define X_CS_PIN           44
```

and also change:

```
#define E1_STEP_PIN        36
#define E1_DIR_PIN         34
#define E1_ENABLE_PIN      30
#define E1_CS_PIN          44
```

to:

```
#define E1_STEP_PIN        54
#define E1_DIR_PIN         55
#define E1_ENABLE_PIN      38
#define E1_CS_PIN          53
```

When the file is changed an saved, [build and upload](http://marlinfw.org/docs/basics/install.html) code to your board and plug the connector of the X stepper into the E1 header.

Answer (score -1):

you can find pin.h in marlin directory and in pin.h file change # define pinout of z motor and extruder motor

Comment: Exactly! I found thease in pinsRAMPS.h thx for help!

Comment: This answer is very terse, and might not include enough details for some users. Perhaps you could improve it by including a bit more detail on what needs to be changed exactly?