# Is there any way I can remap pins so the Z axis outputs through the extruder driver?

Tags: marlin, motor, wanhao

I have a Wanhao Duplicator i3 from which  I have blown the Z axis stepper motor. I would like to be able to have all three axes of motion available for another project. I am trying to see if there's an easy way so that instead of using the Z (blown out) motor driver, it uses the extrude motor driver to control the Z axis. Like when it gets the command to move the Z, it outputs that command through the extruder motor. I'm using Marlin firmware (i3 plus plus) if that helps.

Comment: Which Duplicator is this, a mini or a plus? This could matter for the printer controller board!

Comment: Yes you can, basically, you need to change the pin numbers in the `pins_<boardname>.h` file for the E0 and the Z stepper, like shown in "[How to switch motor outputs and use E1 as X, in Marlin firmware?](/a/5786)".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch motor outputs and use E1 as X, in Marlin firmware?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3925/how-to-switch-motor-outputs-and-use-e1-as-x-in-marlin-firmware)