# Marlin: Switch Y to E1

Tags: marlin, stepper-driver, arduino-mega-2650, kossel

I have an Anycubic Kossel with Trigorilla Motherboard, Mega2560+RAMPS1.4.

I'm using [Marlin 2_0_bugfix](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3661097)

My Y connector is not working anymore so I would like to use E1 connector as Y.
I found a very good solution [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3925/how-to-switch-motor-outputs-and-use-e1-as-x-in-marlin-firmware) but for me for some reason it's not working.

I did that modification what suggested in the pins_RAMPS.h file (for Y of course instead of X), then I compiled it with Arduino 1.8.13 and uploaded to my printer.

After that I flashed firmware then Y (which I plugged to E1) is not moving anywhere. I have never plugged anything to E1 before, so I think the connector port must be good and working.

What I am missing, what's my mistake?

What I did:

```
#define Y_STEP_PIN         36
#define Y_DIR_PIN          34
#define Y_ENABLE_PIN       30
#ifndef Y_CS_PIN
  #define Y_CS_PIN         44
#endif


#define E1_STEP_PIN        60
#define E1_DIR_PIN         61
#define E1_ENABLE_PIN      56
#ifndef E1_CS_PIN
  #define E1_CS_PIN        49
#endif
```

Comment: This should work, I've looked into the pins files for you. Is the stepper driver for E1 working? Is there a stepper driver installed? Just wild guesses. Swap drivers and cables to be sure.

Comment: You were right.I just figured out that the stepper was not working for E1, I will try it with another one. And maybe the Y connector is also good, only the stepper i faulty. Thanks for the idea, I tried a lot of thing without luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you followed [the answer to switch steppers in firmware](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3925/how-to-switch-motor-outputs-and-use-e1-as-x-in-marlin-firmware) to the letter, but changing X for Y, this should work.

I've looked into the pins files for you and concluded that your proposed changes should work.

This leaves you with the following questions:

- Is the stepper driver for E1 working?
- Is there a stepper driver installed?
- Is the cable working/not damaged?

Swap drivers and cables to troubleshoot the problem.